# how to split main.py file into multiple files?

Tags: python

I have 3 files are `listwidget.ui`, `main.py` and `sub.py`.
This listwidget.ui file created by QtDesigner.
Below are my example code of main.py and sub.py.

> Main.py:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys
from PyQt5 import uic
import sub

class UI(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(UI, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi("listwidget.ui", self)
        self.show()
        
        fruit_list = ["Apples", "pears", "oranges", "grapefruits", "strawberries"]
        self.fruit_list = dict.fromkeys(fruit_list, 0)
        for i in self.fruit_list:
            item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(i)
            item.setFlags(item.flags() | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable)
            item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
            self.listWidget.addItem(item)

        self.searchLineEdit.textChanged.connect(self.filter_items)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = UI()
app.exec_()
```

> sub.py:

```
def filter_items(self, text):
    for i in range(self.listWidget.count()):
        item = self.listWidget.item(i)
        item.setHidden(text.lower() not in item.text().lower())
```

Above is my example program. And i have a python program has lost of functions and thousands of line under one class.  I want to split the main coded as "main.py" file into multiple files. How to split this type of Program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research got a solution below:
Added below lines in main.py under the Class:

```
def filter_items(self, text):
    sub.filter_items(self, text)
```

Comment: Why do you need another function for that inside `main`? Why not just call `sub.filter_items` directly?

Comment: Because it cant to be split directly class in to multiple files.

Comment: Your code and question are really not clear. Why does the `filter_items` function in `sub` take a `self` argument? Is it inside another class? If not, why isn't inside the class `UI`?

Comment: Actually  i created a sample program and asked a question because I have a python application file with multiple Functions and thousands of lines. So i want to split in to multiple files. and i can not ask a question for my real application it have thousands of lines and lot of functions. Just i want to split my thousands of lines file in to multiple files. and i searched on internet and got some info and i added the function.

Comment: There is no one definite answer on how to split code to multiple files. It really depends on your code. You should generally group logically-related stuff in the same file. Anyway, as I said, your question is not clear. Is the function from `sub` part of a class? I don't understand why it is not inside the `UI` class. Splitting files is fine, but it makes no sense to split the same class across multiple files

Comment: I told you my other Application has lot of functions and thousands of lines. So i want to edit my application code some times but it is very hard to find the functions and lines so i wanted to split the code into multiple files.  If i edit my question, is it possible to be removed down vote?